# Smooth histogram in python

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn, bins

In my program, I calculate N amounts of three parameters and want to create three histograms for each parameter. I have strict conditions for the histograms. Firstly, it is a condition on the range (at some points histogram should go to zero strictly), and it should be smooth.
I use `np.histogram`, as following:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(Gamm1, bins=100)
center = bins[:-1]
plt.plot(center, hist)
plt.show()
```

but the solution is too sharp. After that, I use the following construction with `seaborn`,

```
snsplot = sns.kdeplot(data['Third'], shade=True)
fig = snsplot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("output2.png")
```

but here approximation goes out of range (range is created from physical conditions).

I think that changing in bins for a `seaborn` solution, as it could be done for `np.histogram`, can help.

But, in the end, I'm looking for some solution, which will be smooth and into given by me range.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a density plot and not a histogram as they are discrete by definition: https://towardsdatascience.com/histograms-and-density-plots-in-python-f6bda88f5ac0

Comment: You're quite right! Thank you so much!